# rhel + how to disable CPU's on my machine

Tags: rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-architecture

We have physical Linux machine with 16 cpus

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
```

We want to disable 14 cpus on that machine , so its actually like we have linux machine with only 2 cpu

In order to achieve this , I did the following

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online
```

and then also run `mpstat`

and we get

```
08:26:13 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
08:26:13 AM  all    0.34    0.00    0.09    0.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.53
08:26:13 AM    0    0.42    0.00    0.12    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.45
08:26:13 AM    1    0.37    0.00    0.10    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.52
08:26:13 AM    2    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    3    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    8    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM    9    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM   10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM   11    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM   12    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM   13    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM   14    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
08:26:13 AM   15    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

[image]

We can see that only 2 cpu’s are online

But I don’t sure if this approach is really works and I need advice
For example how to be sure that any PID's will not use the other 14 cpu’s that are disabled?

Let me know if my procedure , disable the 14 cpu’s  , and process will use only 2 cpus

Comment: If this is for licensing purposes, you’d be better off talking to the vendor...

Comment: on a long term purpose (e.g. not a temporary performance test), I would suggest BIOS disabling.

Comment: @ Stephen Kitt  , yes its about  licensing purposes , we are pay per core quantity , so this is the reason that we want to know the right approach that limit the CPU , from Vendor side when we limit the CPU and application not used the disabled cpu then its ok from his side , but the question is about the procedure that I described , is it really works ?

Comment: @Archemar , can you give example how to disable CPU from BIOS HW side ?

Comment: this depend on hardware, you need to boot to bios (before actual OS boot) and disable hyperthreading (CPU gos from 16 to 8) for instance. In a same situation we end up removing one of the processor. (HP blade 4xx and oracle licencing)

Comment: @Archemar: Not every UEFI will allow that. If he has a server motherboard, that will even be truer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might or might not depending on the application.

If the application simply uses APIs to poll the number of available cores, it might not work because the Linux kernel might return all the cores.

However disabling CPU cores in BIOS must work - it depends on your BIOS implementation, so please consult with your motherboard documentation.

If I were you, I'd approach this issue differently: I'd run the app in a VM and allocate the required number of cores to it. This way your host OS will still be able to use the remaining cores.

Lastly you don't need to run echo 14 times.

Here's a simpler version for bash:

```bsh
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{2..15}/online
```

Lastly make sure you leave two physical cores instead of a single core with HT. To learn your CPU topology run:

```
lscpu -p
```

Normally the Linux kernel first sees physical cores, then HT/SMT cores but I'm not sure it's always the case.

Comment: you said also - "it might not work because the Linux kernel might return all the cores" , any other suggestion how to force the cpu for disabled ant not release the cpu even if application want to use it?

Comment: If you disable CPU cores in BIOS or use virtualization your app will see the exact number of cores you've allocated for it.

Comment: I already check that but we can because its also required license , so only from OS side

Comment: Kudos for virtualization, it is way too overlooked and underrated these days.